# linking against system libraries not found as there was no libuuid.so only libuuid.so.1

Tags: c, linker

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
Fedora 19 Linux localhost.localdomain 3.11.4-201.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 10 14:11:18 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cmake version 2.8.11
```

I am creating a shared library using cmake that links dynamically against some system libraries uuid, asound, crypto, and ssl.

I have set my compiler and linker flags to compile using 32 bit mode:

```
set_target_properties(app_module_sip PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
```

When I compiled I got the following link errors for those libraries (just including the uuid and not the others to keep it short).

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
```

So I did a locate on those libraries to see if they existed

```
/usr/lib/libuuid.so.1
/usr/lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0
/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1
/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

So as the libuuid.so was not there, as I guess that was what it was looking for. I decided to create a soft link:

```
ln -s libuuid.so.1 libuuid.so
```

So now I get the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    12 Oct 23 14:00 libuuid.so -> libuuid.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    16 Sep 18 22:04 libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 20772 Sep 10 16:34 libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

Now when I do the locate I get this:

```
/usr/lib/libuuid.so
/usr/lib/libuuid.so.1
/usr/lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

Everything compiles and links ok, after creating the soft link for each of those libraries.

**Questions**:

1) I am not an expert on Linux, but is it safe to create soft links for system libraries? Could it have an impact somewhere else?

2) Why do the libraries have different version numbers have to have the soft links too? libuuid.so.1.3.0, libuuid.so.1, etc.

Comment: 1. Yes it's safe (it's normally done like this). These are not quite "system libraries". They're nothing special. 2. Because people update their code and software version changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's safe. A soft link is just a link to the library. Deleting the soft link won't have an impact on the original library. But some application may not find the library it depends. For example, it depends on `libuuid.so` instead of `libuuid.so.1`. If you delete the soft link `libuuid.so -> libuuid.so.1`, the linker will complain.

2) Shared library will be named in this way: `lib[name].so.[major].[minor]`. When updating the shared library, if only the minor version number changed, for example, `libuuid.so.1.3.0 --> libuuid.so.1.3.1`, `libuuid.so.1.3.1` will replace `libuuid.so.1.3.0` and the soft link will changed to `libuuild.so.1 -> libuuild.so.1.3.1`. So does the major version changing. In this way, we can manage the versions of the shared library easily.

Answer (score 3):

Installing libuuid-devel will take care of it.

```
$ yum install libuuid-devel
```

Comment: for e.g. ubuntu, the package is `uuid-dev`